# A way to send some value in the wrapped timeout function without using global variables

Tags: javascript, global-variables, settimeout

Subj. Is there a way to put some value from outer variable inside wrapped function for timeout without using global variables?
Example:

```
function OuterFunc(){
    //...
    var localVAR=25;
    setTimeout(function(){ FuncInsideWrap(/*>>>*/localVAR/*<<<*/); },250);
    //...
}
```

I need that because even `OuterFunc` wrapped in another outer function and so on...

Comment: You can use that variable if it's in its lexical scope... Not sure what you are asking here

Comment: @elclanrs Well, I'm sorry. I guess i'm just too sleepy atm =)  
Just to give u a smile:
    `on('questionArrived',function(){
        if(sleepy){
            if( doSomeExtraDebug() || digSomeCallStacks() ) return;
        }
        goToStackOverflow();
    })`